# ant: warning: unmappable character for encoding UTF8

Tags: java, linux, ant

I have seen numerous of questions like mine but they don't answer my question because I'm using ant and I'm not using eclipse. I run this code: `ant clean dist` and it tells me numerous times that `warning: unmappable character for encoding UTF8`.

I see on the Java command that there is a -encoding option, but that doesn't help me cuz I'm using the ant.

I'm on Linux and I'm trying to run the developer version of [Sentrick](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sentrick/); I haven't made no modifications to anything, I just downloaded it and followed all their [instructions](http://sentrick.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=sentrick/sentrick;a=blob;f=doc/readme.txt;h=6ef6ea2789a2f41dbcf542f5f076977f2e519585;hb=HEAD) and it ain't makes no difference. I emailed the developper and they told me it was this problem but I suspect that it is actually something that gotta do with this error at the end:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/daniel/sentricksrc/sentrick/build.xml:22: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/daniel/sentricksrc/sentrick/ant/common-targets.xml:83: Test de.denkselbst.sentrick.tokeniser.components.DetectedAbbreviationAnnotatorTest failed
```

I'm not sure what I'm gonna do now because I really need for it to work

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try to change file encoding of your source files and set the Default Java File Encoding to UTF-8 also.

For Ant:

add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` to your `ANT_OPTS` environment variable

Setting the Default Java File Encoding to UTF-8:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Or you can start up java with an argument `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Comment: I suspect the problem is that some file is encoded in some other encoding but the tool chain is treating it as UTF-8.

Comment: I found how to kill Java with `pkill java` but how do you start it again??

Comment: Using `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` solved the issue for me but still don't understand why it happened. I have been using `ant` for months with a problem. I use **jEdit**  and just changed a line in one of the files and the whole code broke down!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not eclipse or ant. The problem is that you have a build file with special characters in it. Like smart quotes or m-dashes from MS Word. Anyway, you have characters in your XML file that are not part of the UTF-8 character set. So you should fix your XML to remove those invalid characters and replace them with similar looking but valid UTF-8 versions. Look for special characters like &#64 © — ® etc. and replace them with the (c) or whatever is useful to you.

BTW, the bad character is in common-targets.xml at line 83

Answer (score 0):

Changing encoding to Cp 1252 worked for my project with same error. I tried changing eclipse properties several times but it did not help me in any way. I added encoding property to my pom.xml file and the error gone. http://ctrlaltsolve.blogspot.in/2015/11/encoding-properties-in-maven.html