# Unmappable character for encoding ASCII but my files are in UTF-8

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I have the following error launching my ant script:

```
[javac] /****/TextUtils.java:25: error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII
```

But this file is encoded in UTF-8, if i do the info command:

```
/***/TextUtils.java: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Why is this file compiled in ASCII and not in utf-8?

I tried to force the encoding in utf-8 on the javac command in my ant build file but without success

Comment: May be, it hepls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106936/ant-warning-unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf8

Comment: @alexs export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 did the trick... Thank you!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

> Setting the Default Java File Encoding to UTF-8:
>
> export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8

From [ant: warning: unmappable character for encoding UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106936/ant-warning-unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf8)

Comment: ;) I was gonna propose you to post an answer. Thanks for your help again Alex!

Comment: do we need to do this directly within the directory where we run `ant`? because I still get the `ummappable` error sometimes.